# Identify these aluminum parts?

Tags: aluminum, pergola

Today I saw an aluminum structure that’s used as a carwash. It’s a very rudimentary drawing, but this is what it looks like:
[image]

These are the two parts: one’s a base leg and the other connects the leg to the top.

Here are the parts. I would like to use them for a pergola:
[image]
[image][image]

Can anyone identify these parts?

Comment: Did you ever get the condensate pump?

Comment: Have to downvote an obvious "shopping question". It's hard to say specifically where these parts come from. Either those aluminum components were custom made for that application or they are "off the shelf" components supplied from one of many aluminum building manufacturers. Googling "aluminum building components" comes up with a gazillion suppliers/manufacturers who produce buildings of various sizes from backyard pergolas to airplane hangers.

Comment: @EdBeal "Upvotes are not for "correcting" downvotes. It is not your job to take away somebody else's right to vote. Only upvote if you thought that it was a great question/answer, not because you disagreed with somebody else's downvote." – 
Lightness Races in Orbit's profile, c. 2014.

Comment: That's a bespoke parts kit from a manufacturer. Never seen it. *Who* made these isn't a shopping question. It's kinda like the solarium I put on a roof. If I need parts for that I'd have to remember who made them in Florida. *Florian* I think.

Comment: *Who makes this thing in the picture* gets an upvote from me every time. So now I'm also guilty ;)

Comment: the pictures are from a carwash? ... the last picture is scary

Comment: @jsotola  You mean the wet extension cord connection?  I thought the same thing!

Comment: Look for 'marquee suppliers'. We use those constructions a lot in the film industry for medium term outdoor buildings. That looks like a small type, but fairly standard. [I've never been part of the construction so I've no clue what the parts are called.]

Comment: @Mazura , I must not have completely read the comments that said down vote.  but I disagree , I regularly reverse down votes that do not have a comment and have for several years there are questions all the time about how to and what is this , there are photos and nothing about price or where to purchase them. So I do not see this as a shopping question at all. I got tired of answers with code ref being downvoted so I started checking and unless a horrible question if no comment I reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rectangular aluminum tubing.

It's pretty big, probably 4x6, maybe bigger. Sure, it'll be weather resistant, but so will cedar or PT SPF, and the wood will probably be about 10% the cost of the aluminum.

Comment: But what are those connectors?

Comment: @gnicko  Think he means the pieces of aluminum that fit into the posts at the top and connect to the other posts.  Think they might be custom made pieces.

Comment: `But what are those connectors?` ... what are you asking? .... they are aluminum connectors

Comment: It seems that the original question wasn't all that clear in what it was asking about. I identified the tubing, while the OP was asking about the connectors. Clear communication is important in all areas of life.